# Inspiration from the Gods- any examples today?

Tags: yoga, meditation, yajna, spiritual, dhyana

By meditating deeply on God/ gods, can we become more effective in our work and professions. Are there any examples today? That is important because we have to finish our job in best way, before going to the next world. How does it work?

Comment: Does Sri Sri run a course for corporates?

Comment: Swami Vivekananda

Answer (score 0):

Focusing your attention on a single point is meditation. it adds value to humans by focusing on god. so it definitely helps one to focus on what is needed.

https://youtu.be/7ibnkW16iZk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).